# Xcode Simulator Test Parallelization Numbers

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode11.3

When I view my Xcode Preferences, I see Auto, 1, 2, 3, and Max for Simulator Test Preferences:
[image]

However, when my coworker views his settings, he sees Auto, 2, 4, 6, and Max:
[image]

We are both using XCode 11.3.1 version.  What controls this number of simulators that appears for this setting?

Answer (score 0):

It reflects the number of cores of the CPU. You have 4 cores and your coworker has 8.